# Karma/Jasmine not finding required files

Tags: angularjs, jasmine, karma-runner, karma-jasmine

In this Angular/Jasmine test I have a controller that uses a service named `http`. The service is in a file named `http.js` in a `services` folder.

The problem (see error below) is that Karma/Jasmine is not finding the `http` service, even though I have it explicitly declared in `karma.conf.js`. What could be the problem?

```
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0) Testing Bank management should retrieve bank list FAILED

Error: [$injector:unpr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.4.8/$injector/unpr?p0=httpProvider%20%3C-%20http (line 41)

        libs/angular/angular.min.js:41:146
        d@libs/angular/angular.min.js:39:93
        libs/angular/angular.min.js:41:198
        d@libs/angular/angular.min.js:39:93
        e@libs/angular/angular.min.js:39:363
        workFn@libs/angular/angular-mocks.js:2439:26
        inject@libs/angular/angular-mocks.js:2411:41
        test/web/admin/banks/mngbanks.test.js:44:10
        loaded@http://localhost:9876/context.js:151:17
        undefined
        TypeError: undefined is not an object (evaluating 'deferred.resolve') in test/web/admin/banks/mngbanks.test.js (line 70)
        test/web/admin/banks/mngbanks.test.js:70:12
        loaded@http://localhost:9876/context.js:151:17
PhantomJS 2.1.1 (Windows 8 0.0.0): Executed 3 of 3 (1 FAILED) (0.016 secs / 0.021 secs)
Warning: Task "karma:unit" failed. Use --force to continue.
```

karma.conf.js:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: 'c:/apps/public/',
    frameworks: ['jasmine'],
    files: [
        'libs/angular/angular.min.js',
        'libs/angular/angular-mocks.js',
        'app/web/app.js',
        'app/services/http.js',    // <-- service is in this file
        'app/**/*.js',
        'test/**/*.js'
    ],
    exclude: [

    ],
    preprocessors: {},
    reporters: ['progress'],
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['PhantomJS'],
    singleRun: true,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

Jasmine test:

```
describe('Testing management', function () {
    var $scope;
    var deferred;

    var list = {
            data: {
                acc: 2,
                bnks: [
                       {sk:1, nm:"Bank 1", dsc:"Bank 1 description",als:"BK1"},
                       {sk:2, nm:"Bank 2", dsc:"Bank 2 description",als:"BK2"},
                       {sk:3, nm:"Bank 3", dsc:"Bank 3 description",als:"BK3"}
                ]
            }
        };

    var ConstantsMock = {
        ReadMany: 'M'
    };

    function NgTableParamsMock() {
    }

    beforeEach(function () {
       module(moduleName);
       module(function ($provide) {
             $provide.value('NgTableParams', NgTableParamsMock);
             $provide.value('Constants', ConstantsMock);
          });

      inject(function($controller, _$rootScope_, $q, http, $timeout) {

        $scope = _$rootScope_.$new();
        console.log("scope:"+$scope)
        deferred = $q.defer();
        spyOn(http, 'call').and.returnValue(deferred.promise);
        $controller('mngBanksCtl', { 
            $rootScope: _$rootScope_,
            $scope: $scope,
            $timeout: $timeout,
            http: http,
            NgTableParams: NgTableParamsMock,
            Constants: ConstantsMock
        });
      });

  });

  it('should retrieve list', function () {

    deferred.resolve(list);
    $scope.$apply();
    expect($scope.data).toBe(list);
  });
});
```

Comment: Please add the code of your jasmine test

Comment: added the test.

Comment: Under which module is the http service?

Comment: the http service is in the same module, I have a single module in the entire application

Comment: http is the name of your service/factory right? Did you try to loaded using the  $injector service?

Comment: I am currently using something like this, and it worked fine for me https://coderwall.com/p/l4fvmq/injecting-custom-services-in-an-angularjs-unit-test But I am not adding my service as a dependency for the $controller like you did.

Comment: in the link you send me it says how to invoke a service using $injector, however it doesn't say how to inject it in the controller

Comment: and why do you want to inject it inside your controller?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/132219/discussion-between-ps0604-and-manuel-obregozo).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem was that a dependency of the injected service was not included in the list of .js files. I found this by creating a Jasmine isolated test (without Karma) that told me the error, Karma did not